# Elif invalid syntax python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm having an invalid syntax on my elif statements why heres the code:

```
while correct_turns != len(word):
        if correct_turns == len(word):
            finish()
        guess = input("Please guess a letter from above: ")
        elif guess in word and not LettersUnused:
            used_letter(guess,display,LettersUnused)
        elif guess in word and LettersUnused:
            correct(guess,display,correct_turns,LettersUnused)
        elif guess in LettersUnused and not word:
            incorrect(guess,display,LettersUnused)
        elif guess not in LettersUnused:
            used_letter(guess,display,LettersUnused)
        elif len(guess)>1:
            guess_word(guess)
```

Comment: You made chages to your code, correcting the problem yo u initially had, renerign the 2 given answers below uninteligible. You really should not do that, If you are past the first error, just post another question.

Answer (score 2):

Your first `elif` should just be an `if`, given your indentation. The `elif`s aren't really related to the first `if` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the initial `if`, because your `while` loop conditional prevents the loop from being entered.

You cannot otherwise 'continue' an `if` block with another line in between. Change the first `elif` into an `if` to start a new block; you may as well remove the other `if` statement as it'll never execute.

```
while correct_turns != len(word):
    guess = input("Please guess a letter from above: ")
    if guess in word and not LettersUnused:
        used_letter(guess,display,LettersUnused)
    elif guess in word and LettersUnused:
        correct(guess,display,correct_turns,LettersUnused)
    elif guess in LettersUnused and not word:
        incorrect(guess,display,LettersUnused)
    elif guess not in LettersUnused:
        used_letter(guess,display,LettersUnused)
    elif len(guess)>1:
        guess_word(guess)
```

Comment: it now gives me an inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indention, iv'e checked it and there's nothing wrong with the indention I've used the tabify region to fix it but nothing works. (its on the first if)

Comment: @Programer4life: You really should avoid using tabs altogether. Run your script with `python -tt scriptname.py` and fix everything that finds.

Comment: And, of course, configure your editor program not to use tabs _at all_ , when editing Python files(this is extremely important)